# Is it possible to isolate an individual atom?

Tags: atomic-physics

I was reading about molecules and wondering about whether they could be individually isolated and "held" or "photographed" in some sense.

Google showed that a [rubidium atom was isolated](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=130268498), but it left out lower-level details.

Is it possible to isolate an individual atom? If so, what is it isolated in? How is it, so to speak, "isolated from" or "separate from reality"? Wondering what is actually going on in the atom's environment at that moment. I have some undergraduate physics background, but not much beyond that.

Comment: This is done all the time. Look up ion traps in the context of quantum computing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's been done for a long time. Google "atomic force microscopy". And click on images to see lots of pictures of individual atoms/molecules/etc, e.g.,

http://iopscience.iop.org/0953-8984/labtalk-article/48480